# Is zero amount transaction possible with paypal methods?

Tags: php, paypal, transactions, payment-gateway, paypal-subscriptions

Is it possible to do transaction with zero amount in paypal methods like express checkout or standard? I want to do auto payments in paypal express or standard methods. In which is it possible I call request and It will make auto transaction from customer paypal account like it did in Paypal recurring method. I do not want to use paypal recurring method because I am managing my own payment schedules and do not want to use its default recurring system.

I am using autorize.net CIM method also. which is working fine right now and I am calling payment request and its doing payment. I also want to do zero amount transaction in that case.

can any one help on this point?

Answer (score 1):

NO,

You need to bypass to zero value.

Means Just do all thing proper except real payment. i.e. order entry, shipping etc. just in it your transaction id is not available.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to be able to charge the buyer later down the road, instead of charging them immediately -- is that right?

If so, then you need to use Billing Agreements and Reference Transactions.  See https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/ for more information.

Note that you will need to get approval from PayPal before you can start creating billing agreements.