# Amount must be greater than zero, PayPal/Braintree payment

Tags: php, paypal, sdk, braintree

I have an app that sells events, some events have zero-dollar price. Thus, I receive this message from PayPal:

```
Amount must be greater than zero
```

However, if I remove the need to make a payment, one user can order all the tickets for an event. So, what's the way to make users go through the payment process without making a charge.

Bear in mind, it'd be great to make as little change to the process in terms of generating a Nonce from frontend and sending it to backend to make the charge it.

I'm using [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-braintree-sdk/get-started/) payment scenario.

This is the function that returns the error message:

```
public function chargeNonce($nonce) {
    $gateway = $this->createPayPalGateway();
    $amount = $this->payment_params['number_of_tickets'] * $this->payment_params['event_price'];
    $result = $gateway->transaction()->sale([
      'amount' => $amount,
      'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce,
      'options' => [
        'submitForSettlement' => True,
        'paypal' => [
            'description' => "Billing Notification",// For email receipt
        ],
      ],
    ]);

    dd($result);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: check amount variable value  ?

Comment: but then a user can enter a bogus credit card and then I check the amount is zero and I give him tickets... I need the process to go through paypal gateway.

Comment: I need a way (or a workaround) to charge users zero-amount.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740935/is-zero-amount-transaction-possible-with-paypal-methods